# Extend Spring Data Repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-repositories

I would like to introduce a `<T> T findOrCreate(Supplier<Optional<T>> finder, Supplier<T> factory)` to all of my repositories.
So created a new Interface

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ExtendedJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    T findOrCreate(Supplier<Optional<T>> finder, Supplier<T> factory);
}
```

.

```
public class ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements ExtendedJpaRepository<T, ID> {

    private final JpaEntityInformation entityInformation;
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public T findOrCreate(Supplier<Optional<T>> finder, Supplier<T> factory) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("No implemented yet");
    }
}
```

Then I use this interface in my concrete repositories, e.g. RecipeIngredientRepository:

```
public interface RecipeIngredientRepository extends ExtendedJpaRepository<RecipeIngredient, Long> {}
```

When I finally inject the repository to my service I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'recipeIngredientRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property find found for type RecipeIngredient! Did you mean 'id'?
```

It is searching for a `find` property in my entitiy `RecipeIngredient`. I did not want it to do this. I think this is related to [JPA Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods). So I changed the name from `findOrCreate` to `xxx` to Bypass any query method detection - without success. It searches for a `xxx` property then.

What does make spring data look for this property?
I'm using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your customized repository implementation via `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl.class)`.

Take a look at the reference docs: [Adding custom behavior to all repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories).

Comment: Thank you! Gosh, I did follow this documentation! But I used @EnableJpaRepositories("org.project.data.repository") which specifies basePackages instead of the repositoryBaseClass. I did not expect the error at the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @md911de answer:

So what you can is to define a generic interface which has the base method that you want to have in all of your repositories:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface BaseGenericReactiveMongoRepository<T> : 
ReactiveMongoRepository<T, String> {
   fun patch(id: String, fields: Map<String, Any>): Mono<T>
}
```

Then you need to implement this and inform spring to use the implementation class for implementing the interface.

```
class SimpleBaseGenericReactiveMongoRepository<ENTITY>(
        private val entityInformation: MappingMongoEntityInformation<ENTITY, String>,
        private val template: ReactiveMongoTemplate
) : SimpleReactiveMongoRepository<ENTITY, String>(entityInformation, template),
        BaseGenericReactiveMongoRepository<ENTITY> {

    private val eventPublisher: ApplicationEventPublisher?

    init {
        val context = template.converter.mappingContext as MongoMappingContext
        val indexCreator = MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator(context) { collectionName ->
            IndexOperationsAdapter.blocking(template.indexOps(collectionName))
        }
        eventPublisher = MongoMappingEventPublisher(indexCreator)
    }

    override fun patch(id: String, fields: Map<String, Any>): Mono<ENTITY> {
        val collection = entityInformation.collectionName
        val query = Query(Criteria.where("_id").`is`(id))
        val document = Document()

        return findById(id)
                .flatMap { entity ->
                    maybeEmitEvent(BeforeConvertEvent<ENTITY>(entity, collection))

                    document.putAll(fields)

                    val update = Update()

                    fields
                            .filter { entry ->
                                !hashSetOf("_id", "createdAt", "createdBy", "modifiedAt", "modifiedBy").contains(entry.key)
                            }
                            .forEach { entry -> update.set(entry.key, entry.value) }

                    maybeEmitEvent(BeforeSaveEvent<ENTITY>(entity, document, collection))

                    template.updateFirst(query, update, collection)
                }
                .then(findById(id)).map { entity ->
                    maybeEmitEvent(AfterSaveEvent<ENTITY>(entity, document, collection))
                    entity
                }
    }

    private fun <T> maybeEmitEvent(event: MongoMappingEvent<T>) {
        eventPublisher?.publishEvent(event)
    }

}
```

And the last part is to inform spring data.

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(
    basePackages = ["**.repository"],
    repositoryBaseClass = SimpleBaseGenericReactiveMongoRepository::class
)
class MongoConfiguration
```

Now you can use the interface as a base interface for your repository and have the functionality for your domain.

```
interface BookRepository : BaseMongoRepository<Book> {

    findByNameContainingIgnoreCaseAndVisibileIsTrue(name:String): Flux<Book>

}
```

If you need a working example, you are welcome to check my medium:

https://medium.com/@ghahremani/extending-default-spring-data-repository-methods-patch-example-a23c07c35bf9